# Check if the typeof(object) in a List is a reference type

Tags: c#, list, object, typeof

this seems odd to me:

```
if(customerList.Count > 0)
{
   if(typeof(customerList[0]).IsReferenceType)
   {
      // do what I want
   }
}
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Can you make the question clear? What do you want to actually do?

Comment: see my title question :) There is a question...

Comment: Still not very clear. Please edit the question so that it contains the crucial information that clarifies why the existing answers are insufficient.

Comment: Hi this seems odd to me: "How would you do it?" It doesn't seem like a question that explains exactly what you are asking...

Answer (score 9):

1. To determine whether the first item in a list is an object of a reference type:

   ```
   bool isReferenceType = !(customerList[0] is ValueType);
   ```
2. To determine whether a list is a `List<T>` for some `T` that is a reference type:

   ```
   var listType = customerList.GetType();
   if (!listType.IsGeneric || listType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(List<>))
       // It’s not a List<T>
       return null;
   return !listType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsValueType;
   ```

Comment: The most Exception I got because the customerList is empty and there is no index... :P

Comment: How could I retrieve the isReferenceType when the List has no objects? but List<T> says its of type T like Customer. Actually I do not add a customer Object to find out my List takes customers of type Customer...

Comment: @Lisa: You’re probably looking for the second solution in my answer. (It’s still not very clear though. Why can’t you just say what you’ve got and what you need?)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to determine the actual type of the generic parameter of a generic collection. Like determining at runtime what is a T of a particular `List<T>`. Do this:

```
Type collectionType = typeof(customerList);
Type parameterType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
bool isReference = !parameterType.IsValueType;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a `List<structImplementingIEnumerator>` will behave differently from a `List<IEnumerator>` which holds instances of `structImplementingIEnumerator`.  What matters is whether the list encapsulates items, or references to items.  If the list encapsulates references to items, it doesn't matter much whether those items themselves derive from `ValueType`--they'll behave like class objects in just about every way except for a likely-broken implementation of `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isReferenceType = !(customerList[0] is ValueType);
```

EDIT

Or are you looking for something like:

```
bool listIsOfReferenceTypeObjects = !myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].IsValueType;
```

Comment: Do I really need to tell not accessing List`s index 0 when the list.Count is zero?

Answer (score -1):

ok that worked and I get no exception, when the customerList is empty.

```
Type collectionType = customerList.GetType();
   Type parameterType = collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
   bool isReference = !parameterType.IsValueType;
```

@Adesit you get a point because your sample was right except the first line :P

Comment: this is precisely identical to the second point in my answer, except that mine doesn’t crash when it’s not a generic type.

Comment: @Timwi Hm you edited your solution, maybe I haven`t read it. I just need to know wether the 'T' of a List is a value type (int) or reference type (custom class). On my side nothing crashes.

Comment: Of course it crashes! Try passing in *anything* that isn’t a generic type, e.g. a `string`...

Comment: I havent checked your suggestion yet because somehow I feel we mean different things...: I will make an example. The user could plug a List<Customer> (Reference type) to my DataSource or a List<int> (Value type). I want to check for those types because if he plugs a List<int> I will throw an exception, because only a Reference type is allowed having a property which can be again a value type.